# Is there any Android Facebook SDK or API available?

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

is there any ANDROID SDK Available for New android application 
i got one link that not Supporting the link is: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk.git 
Any Other for SDk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/) or [this](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/) Java Facebook API.